# Avoid defining a function in a loop when using an IIFE

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have the following following code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    this.hands[0].cards[i].img.on('mousedown', (function (i) {
        var j = i;
        return function (event) {
            self.hands[0].cards[j].holdCard();
        };
    })(i));
}
```

This is working fine for my needs but JSHint is complaining:

> [L1164:C10] W083: Don't make functions within a loop.

How can I keep JSHint happy by rewriting this differently?

Comment: Define the function outside of the loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace the IIFE with a separate function outside the loop:

```
function createHandler(j, self) {
    return function (event) {
        self.hands[0].cards[j].holdCard();
    };
}
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    this.hands[0].cards[i].img.on('mousedown', createHandler(i, this));
}
```

Useful reference: [JSLint Errors Explanation](http://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop/) (thanks to user1671639 for the link).

Comment: +1 You got it before I do a jsfiddle.  Also here is good explanation of that error [JSLint Error Explanations](http://jslinterrors.com/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I added it to the answer body.